# Getting OS version with NDK in C

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I'm writing a C program which I want to execute on my Desktop running Linux and also on an Android device.
I have to make some Desktop specific things and some Android specific things.
My question is, is there a way to get the OS version in C so I can handle if the program is executed on the Desktop or on the Android device?

Comment: if you just want to check if you are using android you could always use c/c++ preprocessor macros to check, `#if defined(__unix__) && __ANDROID__ #define PLATFORM_ANDROID #endif` if you want to check the API version for android this way use do `#if defined(__unix__) && __ANDROID__ #include <android/api-level.h> #if defined(__ANDROID__) && __ANDROID_API__ == 0x00000001 #defined ANDROID_API_1 #endif #endif`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your native code, you could use `property_get()`, something like this:

```
#include <cutils/properties.h>

// ...

int myfunction() {
    char sdk_ver_str[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX] = "0";
    property_get("ro.build.version.sdk", sdk_ver_str, "0");
    sdk_ver = atoi(sdk_ver_str);
    // ...   
}
```

On desktop, `property_get()` should return empty string.

Note that in starting from Android 6, `<cutils/properties.h>` is not available in SDK, use `__system_property_get` as follows:

```
#include <sys/system_properties.h>

// ...

int myfunction() {
    char sdk_ver_str[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX];
    if (__system_property_get("ro.build.version.sdk", sdk_ver_str)) {
        sdk_ver = atoi(sdk_ver_str);
    } else {
        // Not running on Android or SDK version is not available
        // ...
    }
    // ...   
}
```

You can use `adb shell getprop` to see all possible Android properties. But, be aware that not all of them are supported by all devices.

---

**UPDATE**: If you don't need OS version, but simply want to tell if your C/C++ code is running on Android, very simple way to tell is to check if environment variable `ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE` exists (on Android 7 or older), or if socket `/dev/socket/property_service` exists (Android 8 or newer), something like this:

```
include <stdlib.h>
include <unistd.h>
// ...

if (getenv("ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE")) {
    // running under Android 7 or older
} else if (access("/dev/socket/property_service", F_OK) == 0) {
    // running under Android 8 or newer
} else {
    // running on desktop
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find `<cutils/properties.h>` in my NDK, but using `__system_property_get` from `<sys/system_properties.h>` worked.

Comment: @weiyin please send this comment as an answer

Comment: property_get is from cutils, which is not part of the NDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744108/cutils-not-included-in-ndk I don't think cutils is meant for app development and the implementation in /system/lib/libcutils.so on your user's device could be incompatible to the <cutils/properties.h> you used at compile time.

Comment: @vulcanraven, updated with solution for recent Android versions

Comment: what can I do if the getenv returns null?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly: unfortunately, since this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/f8562c5%5E%21/) `ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE` is not present in Android 8 (Oreo) and later. it means you have to use `__system_property_get()` method

Answer (score 12):

`property_get()` did not work for me, instead I used `__system_property_get()`.

```
#include <sys/system_properties.h>

void foo() {
    char osVersion[PROP_VALUE_MAX+1];
    int osVersionLength = __system_property_get("ro.build.version.release", osVersion);
}
```

`ro.build.version.release` is a string like "6.0". You can also get `ro.build.version.sdk` to get the sdk level, which is a string like "23".

Comment: I think you don't need the +1 in the char array length because __system_property_get is "copying [the] value and a \0 terminator to the provided pointer.  The total bytes copied will be no greater than PROP_VALUE_MAX." https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/49f0a8f23bba188466c6ee3652858ef4da228c6f/libc/include/sys/system_properties.h

Answer (score 6):

NDK provide direct api to get app target sdk version or api level

```
android_get_device_api_level
android_get_application_target_sdk_version
```

See the [ndk official document](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/apilevels).

Comment: This should be at the top.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the java native interface, you can use the java function to get the sdk version number, which is less dependent on android version.

```
int api_version( struct android_app *app ) {

    JNIEnv* env;
    app->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread( &env, NULL );

    // VERSION is a nested class within android.os.Build (hence "$" rather than "/")
   jclass versionClass = env->FindClass("android/os/Build$VERSION" );
   jfieldID sdkIntFieldID = env->GetStaticFieldID(versionClass, "SDK_INT", "I" );

   int sdkInt = env->GetStaticIntField(versionClass, sdkIntFieldID );
   app->activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread();
   return sdkInt;
}
```

Comment: This will give exact same result as `property_get("ro.build.version.sdk")`, but is much more complicated

Comment: At least in my development environment (nVidia AndroidWorks, Visual Studio 2013), property_get is not readily available as it is not part of the stock android ndk. I assume I could find the source for property_get and add it to my project. However, after 10 minutes into that project, I realized JNI would do nicely. I post my answer here not to say that people can't or shouldn't use your answer, but to give people more options.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Remember to also call `env->DeleteLocalRef(versionClass)`

Answer (score 4):

How about using AConfiguration_getSdkVersion() API?

```
#include <android/configuration.h>
...
auto apilevel = AConfiguration_getSdkVersion(app->config);
LOGI("Device API Level %d", apilevel);
```

Comment: Where do you get the `app` variable from?

Comment: @SimonWarta I think you need to build native apps to access this `android_app`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/configuration#aconfiguration_getsdkversion

Answer (score 0):

```
#if defined(__linux__)
// Linux-based OS

#if defined(__ANDROID__)
// Android OS
#else
// other Linux-based OS
#endif

#endif
```

See [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/) for reference. The caveat is that any linux system sets `__linux__`, and Android sets that **and** `__ANDROID__`. For windows it's `_WIN32` for most use cases.~

You can also use `/path/to/your/ndk/compiler -dM -E - < /dev/null` to see all the flags available to you.